# Manga in which the female protagonist is reincarnated as a toddler in a different world

Tags: story-identification, manga

The Female MC gets reincarnated as a young girl, about toddler age, into another world. Her village gets attacked by bandits, and she uses magic to defend her injured mother. A young female knight that hides her face comes to see her, and she travels to the capital where she meets the king. She becomes one of the youngest wizards ever and defeats another wizard that was hostile towards her

Comment: Was she reincarnated from another world? Had a bit of a crush on one of the male knights who showed up (him, of course, treating her like his daughter instead)?

Comment: That was quick, yes that's the right one, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Shindou Sephilia no Gekokujou Program*](https://anilist.co/manga/110806/Shindou-Sephilia-no-Gekokujou-Program/) by Tougarashi, Hideyu (Art) and Ashidaka, Takami (Story) perhaps?

> Meet Sefiria. She may be just a baby now, but she holds a dangerous secret - she has memories of her previous life as a Japanese salarywoman.
>
> After experiencing the hell of living in such a rigid society like Japan beforehand, Sefiria wants to avoid making that same mistake in her second life. That’s when she remembered a famous saying back in her previous life:
>
> “At ten years old, you can be a prodigy. At fifteen years old, you can be a genius. At twenty years old, you’ll just be a normal person.”
>
> While the new world she was born in considers adulthood to start at the age of 15, Sefiria has a repository of knowledge from her old life to help back her up. Can she become a prodigy at an early age, revolutionize her world, and ensure herself a slow life that any Japanese reader would love to self-insert into?

[image: Front cover of Shindou Sephilia no Gekokujou Program]

[This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/puhnl3/female_baby_isekai_manga_looking_for_it_anyone/) mentions the bandits, mother, magic, and female knight.

> MC reincarnated to female baby, she was a toddler around 1 year old. Her father were soldier and sent to the war, his father seems can use magic which was rare in her world which was medieval fantasy. She live with her mother and one big brother who was around 8-10 years old. There is a female knight who come to her village and work there to protect the village.
>
> Let's fast forward, basically mc learned magic and can use it despite being baby, at night, horde of bandits attacked her village, one of bandit break to her house and try to rape her mother, the brother try to stop it but the bandit then try to slash him using his sword but the mother hugging the boy and got slashed in her back. MC who was very angry then use magic, like fire ball or ice lance, forgot but she can use any elements, and kill the bandit. MC then walk to the village , her mother and brother were unconscious but safe. She then go to the village square and find the female knight dueling the bandit leader, but all the villager were gathered and put as hostage. The bandit leader played with her(she can defeat him) saying if she hurt him just by one drop of blood, he will ordered his man to kill all the villagers. She then can only defend while the bandit leaders laughed, mc then pretended to be baby, walking near the villager, the bandits just laugh at her and think whose baby it is, if she cry we will kill her, but then mc use high tier magic and killed all the bandits. The bandit leader were shocked when he seeing it and the female knight use that chance to kill him. In the end mc saved the village, and mc as baby were summoned to the 4 lords or something who equal to sage in powers after hearing the report about mc magic powers. She kinda got elected as the 5th lord or something, i forgot basically high rank, to the point it was equal to noble rank. So don't know how to find it haha hope i can find it

Found with a search for `manga isekai reincarnated as female toddler great with magic`

Comment: ^_^ Glad I could find it for you, although I think I was thinking of a different work.